# iOS XCUITest isAccessibilityElement always false

Tags: ios, automated-tests, accessibility, xcuitest

Simple test case for UILabel
Given UILabel has following properties set:

```
    label.accessibilityLabel = "Hello"
    label.accessibilityTraits = .staticText
    label.isAccessibilityElement = false
```

This test is successful despite "isAccessibilityElement = false", this test gives false positive result - if I run app Voiceover won't read this element.

```
        XCTAssert(app.staticTexts["Hello"].exists)
```

So I thought adding additional check for isAccessibilityElement, but running UI test it is always false(also when label.isAccessibilityElement = true).

```
        XCTAssert( app.staticTexts["Hello"].isAccessibilityElement) // always false
```

Am I missing something or "isAccessibilityElement" is not testable?
Is there any other approach how to check if element will be actually picked up by assistant e.g. Voiceover?